# Chrome Won't Go Away

Tags: google-chrome, dock

I was having some issues with chrome, where it would crash all the time for no reason. Then, recently, it crashed, but in my dock it says it's still running. I deleted it from my applications but it is still in my dock, and when I try to force quit it, nothing happens. I can't drag it out of my dock or do anything to move it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have what's known in Unix as a zombie process. Unlike the less friendly dead people, zombies in your computer won't eat your brains, and they also won't do much of anything else. They don't take up any resources. It's basically just going to sit there until you reboot, or you lop its head off. OS X doesn't seem to tend its fences when it comes to zombies. I can think of a game or two they should play which would help them out with this a bit...

For more info on Zombies, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_vs._Zombies

or, even more helpfully:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

Comment: Or better the Doom mode to allow sysadmin to fight (kill) processes http://www.cs.unm.edu/~dlchao/flake/doom/ unfortunately for Linux - but as Doom was available on NeXT should be doable :)